# What is this control called? (From an example app)

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I need to know the name of the control that appears under the "Facebook" heading in the image below, using Visual Studio 2013.

[image]

Can anyone tell me?

Comment: The [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Can you please try to be more clear?

Comment: i can fill it, load from file text etc

Comment: It could be a ListBox/Datagrid/GridView or even custom control to achieve it. You can take a look at basic controls in the language you are trying to achieve it.

Comment: In Winforms it would be either a  ListView or a DataGridView. Possibly a custom made control (unlikely)

Comment: its DataGridView - thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

*Collecting comments in an answer.*

From [p.s.w.g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1715579/p-s-w-g):

> The `DataGrid` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx))?

From [asb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3437575/asb):

> It could be a ListBox/Datagrid/GridView or even custom control to achieve it. You can take a look at basic controls in the language you are trying to achieve it.

From [TaW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3152130/taw):

> In Winforms it would be either a ListView or a DataGridView. Possibly a custom made control (unlikely)

From [Mateusz Kowalski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4015710/mateusz-kowalski):

> its DataGridView - thanks guys :)